# Touchscreen multi-touch not working on Sony Vaio Duo 11 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: multi-touch, touchscreen, vaio

I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux in general. I installed 16.04 on this laptop yesterday. Windows was removed, Ubuntu is the only OS installed.  The touchscreen works with a single finger for pointing and tapping. Multi-finger gestures do not work such as pinch and spread. In addition, a single finger touch and hold is not emulating a right mouse click.

This documentation page suggests that multi-touch should work:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Laptop/Sony/Vaio/Duo11/Trusty

Can anyone suggest a few basic things to check to see if something is configured incorrectly in this installation?